C++ kill() crashes linux to login screen
i am having problems with a project of mine,
i am creating child processes with fork and then terminating them with kill(pid,SIGINT) and then restarting them
after the second time interrupting the process linux will crash to the login screen. so it is also possible that gnome or my windowmanager is actually the thing that is crashing
i dont know how to fix this.
here is the code that results in a crash
#include <iostream>
#include <signal.h>
#include <thread>

const int CHILDREN = 3;
bool is_active;

using namespace std;

void signalHandler(int signum)
{
    cout << "Interrupt signal (" << signum << ") received.\n";

    // cleanup and close up stuff here
    // terminate program

    is_active = false;
}

pid_t fork_process(int process_nr)
{
    pid_t c_pid;
    c_pid = fork();
    if (c_pid == -1)
    {
        perror("failure to fork new process");
        return -1;
    }
    else if (c_pid == 0)
    { // child process
        signal(SIGINT, signalHandler);
        is_active = true;
        while (is_active)
        {
        }
        cout << "child " << process_nr << " EXIT" << endl;
        return -1;
    }
    return c_pid;
}

pid_t restart_process(int process_nr, pid_t pid)
{
    cout << "restart process " << process_nr << endl;
    pid_t new_c_pid;
    kill(pid, SIGINT);//THIS IS WHERE THE CRASH HAPPENS

    sleep(3);

    new_c_pid = fork_process(process_nr);
    return new_c_pid;
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    int ret;
    pid_t c_pid[CHILDREN];

    for (int i = 0; i < CHILDREN; i++)
    {
        ret = fork_process(i);
        if (ret == -1)
            return 0;
        c_pid[i] = ret;
        cout << "parent created child " << i << " with c_pid " << c_pid[i] << endl;
    }

    int to_restart = 1;

    this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::seconds(16));

    // restart the selected process
    c_pid[to_restart] = restart_process(to_restart, c_pid[to_restart]);

    this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::seconds(16));

    // restart the selected process
    c_pid[to_restart] = restart_process(to_restart, c_pid[to_restart]);//THIS IS WHERE THE CRASH HAPPENS

    this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::seconds(16));
    return 0;
}


with the Makefile
CC = g++
CFLAGS = -Wall -g

output: main.o
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o output main.o
main.o: main.cpp
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c  main.cpp
clean:
    rm *.o output

thanks for the help.
restarting once works fine so i dont know how calling it twice would create the crash
i have run it with gdb and have marked where the crash happens. however it will not happen immediately but after 5 second after executing the kill() function

OT: The parent process should reap the child-processes when they exit. By calling one of the wait family of functions.

Why is to_restart always 1? That looks wrong.

Add flushing of std::cout (use std::endl instead of newlines), and add more output. That should help you narrow it down. Redirect the output to a file (or pipe to the tee command to both save output to a file and also show it in the terminal). Example of added output, the parent pid in the child processes, the pid to send SIGINT to (and the current process pid). And much more (like all arguments to all functions, and all return values from all functions).

@JesperJuhl since i want to restart process 1 twice

If you got the login screen, Linux didn't crash. Your processes crashed, because you killed them. What exactly did you expect?

When you restart_process, you are not checking the result value for -1. So, when the forked child returns, it continues like it were on the main process, except that the next time it kills the presumed child, it calls kill(-1, ...) which kills everything you have permission to kill.
Something like that, anyway.

thnx for the help, i really should have seen this..... why would it crash linux to the desktop tough? would have probably seen it if i had output of it.....

@robybert I haven't used a desktop-Unix in ages, but the way this usually works is that the login-screen is run as the root user so it can access your password and actually do a login for your user. When that happens, the desktop environment is run as your user, and of course everything you run yourself. kill(-1) kills everything that you are allowed to kill -- which means every program that your user has started, including the desktop environment that you're using. When that dies, the login manager notices and shows you a login screen again.
